# Passing a null to struct

Tags: c, struct

Hello Fellow programmers here is a code I have. Now there is a possibility that I don't necessarily want to pass an `acc` struct.Instead a `pas _str` is the only struct I want to pass, but I cant assign null to a struct like I have seen on some post here so , wondering if I am just gonna have to make a next function for search.

```
int Rcrd_Srch(FILE *,struct acc,struct pas_Str,int);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the entire `acc` and `pas_Str` structures (which involves making copies when calling the function), consider passing pointers to the structures.  That avoids unnecessary copying, and also gives you the possibility to pass `NULL`.

```
int Rcrd_Srch(FILE *, struct acc const *, struct pas_Str const *, int);
```

Comment: could you tell me more about this?